# Store Rust's struct instantiated in JS in Rust's vector on the wasm side

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

How can I store JS instantiated object in Rust's struct and make computations on it?

I created an example based on [tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/implementing.html).

The rust part:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Body {
    position: f32
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Body {
    pub fn new() -> Body {
        Body {
            position: 0.
        }
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct World {
    bodies: Vec<Body>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl World {
    // .. new etc
    pub fn add_body(&mut self, object: Body) {
        self.bodies.push(Body);
    }

    pub fn step(&mut step) {
        // do something with bodies
    }
}
```

```js
const world = World.new();
const body = Body.new()

console.log('body', body);
world.add_body(body);
console.log('after added', body);
```

Immediately after `body` is added to the world it loses its reference.

Console.log result:

```
body Body {ptr: 1118264}
index.js:28 after added Body {ptr: 0}
```

Is it possible to store the reference in JS? My use case: I handle all interaction etc on JS side and to only heavy calculations on wasm side.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `add_body`, it passes ownership of the value to your World, which immediately moves it into the vec. If you imagine this same code in rust:

```rust
let mut world = World::new();
let body = Body::new();

println!("body: {:?}", body);
world.add_body(body);
println!("body added: {:?}", body);
```

It would fail to compile on the second println, because it was moved in the `add_body` call.

If your objects live primarily in JS land, you should work with them in rust land as JsValue references. Here's an example for the binding of the Array global that you can use as a reference: https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/src/js_sys/lib.rs.html#127